Tying data to a user's account
I am writing a signup form for my django site. And basically I want them to hit submit and create the account. I have written code that creates a license key when they hit it but I don't know how to tie it to their account. Any ideas?
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from .forms import SignupForm
from Functions.average_getter_shortened import baseline
from Functions.today_checker import today_getter
from Functions.license_key import license_getter
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            try:
                license_key = license_getter(access_key='access_key')
            except:
                license_key = 'Key'
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, r'registration\license_key.html', {'license_key' : license_key})
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, r'registration\signup.html', {'form': form})

I tried to implement user.save() after the except statement but then the website wouldnt redirect to the license_key page. I also tried my best to search up 'how to tie data to a user's account' but no luck.
I know this is quite a stupid question but I am new to django and couldn't find any resources on how to do this.

With a model...

But perhaps more important, since the SignupForm, and the user model if it is a custom one.

But like how do I save to a model

I just used the normal user model and saved the licensekey to it
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from .forms import SignupForm
from Functions.average_getter_shortened import baseline
from Functions.today_checker import today_getter
from Functions.license_key import license_getter
from accounts.models import CustomUser
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            try:
                license_key = license_getter(access_key='access_key')
            except:
                license_key = 'Key'
            user.license_key = license_key
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, r'registration\license_key.html', {'license_key' : license_key})
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, r'registration\signup.html', {'form': form})


This will not persist, once you retrieve the user, the extra data is gone.

It seems to work, in my views I was able to retrieve the license_key data. But thanks for the help

There are a lot of examples out there, but this is what i do. I created a "Profile" model and then tied it to their User record. This prevents me from having to jack with the User record while also being able to store/track whatever i want and tied to the User account.
When a user is created, it will automatically generate a Profile record setting defaults... and grant access to a group automatically. I need to refine how i'm identifying the group better than using the PK, but this works good enough for now.
While this may not solve your issue specifically, i think the structure/processes could be easily adapted to accomplish what you're looking to do.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discipline_assessed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Assessed?')
    allow_skills = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Allow Access To Skills Matrix Tool?')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user',]
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        try:
            if created:
                Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
                instance.groups.add(Group.objects.get(id=1))
                instance.save()
        except Exception as err:
            print('Error creating user profile!')
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()

